# Is there a way i can detect if a form was submited on a webview?

Tags: android, webview, submit

I have a webview with a thirdparty payment company. I don't want to get the post data i just want to know if the user already submitted to lock the actions in the app so he can't do anything till the process is done.

Accoording the android documentation WebViewCLient doesn't do this on [shouldOverrideUrlLoading()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)) with post methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way to do exactly this but my work around was overriding shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) on web client and then used there request.hasGesture() to know that the request was fired by an user action

```
private final WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() { 
@Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                if(request.hasGesture()){
                    //block screen
                }
            }

            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
        }
}
```